# How do I properly set link prefetch headers in Express 4?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, chromium, etherpad

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ) the correct approach is to send the header:

```
Link: </images/big.jpeg>; rel=prefetch
```

So my express syntax is:

```
res.header('Link', '</images/big.jpeg>; rel=prefetch');
```

and I see it land in my browser as:

```
Link:</images/big.jpeg>; rel=prefetch
```

But chrome never attempts to download the image..  The meta and link approaches work fine..

Am I setting the header wrong or is the browser failing to process the header value?

UDPATE: Okay so it looks like I'm doing things right but Chrome 43 & Chromium 43 on Linux/Ubuntu doesn't have support for this yet.  This is working fine in Firefox 38..

Could it be that Chromium is just not showing the prefetching in the Network tab?

UPDATE 2: So it does look like Chrome/Chromium is hiding the file transfers from the Network tab.  If someone can confirm this I'd appreciate it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set prefetch for one file in Express 4+..

```
res.set('Link', '<static/js/file1.js>; rel=prefetch');
```

For multiple files.

```
res.set('Link', '<static/js/file1.js>; rel=prefetch, <static/js/file2.js>; rel=prefetch');
```

Do NOT attempt to test this in Chrome, Chrome will lie to you and show it as not working if you investigate under Network tab.  Always test with [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/new/).

[You can see me implementing this in a larger project in context here.](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/pull/2697/files)

Comment: how do we add prefetch or preload when the files have a dynamic hash, like: styles.b2d783724150de9a2373.css